# "Invalid Test URL" error after integrating at&t speechToText api in apigee

Tags: apigee

I created API Proxy of ATT SpeechtoText api (https://api.att.com/speech/v3/speechToText) and added the mandatory headers using Assign Message policy. When I am not providing any file then the status received is HTTP/1.1 200 OK with following response:

```
{
  "Recognition":  {
    "Info":  {
      "metrics":  {
        "audioBytes": 0,
        "audioTime": 0
      }
    },
    "ResponseId": "ecc4b3590ec4955a7eae51eb527bd6fb",
    "Status": "Speech Not Recognized"
  }
```

}

But when I attach/upload a wav file it gives "Invalid Test URL" in response.

Comment: Can you provide the proxy zip file by exporting it. I would be easy to analyze the root cause.

Comment: @Srikanth Yes can you please provide your email address?

Comment: Circling back: Bundle was provided. Could reproduce the issue. But they solved it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If its file upload.It needs to be multipart request.Is this a multipart request?

Comment: Yes its a multipart request. I am using apigee console to upload audio file.